# How to replace fixed width and height on a custom windows phone control?

Tags: xaml, user-controls, windows-phone, expression-blend

I want to make a control displaying three bitmap like this :

[image]

My problem is that I don't want to have fixed "Width" and "Height" for bitmap. They must take all available space where they are and keeping their aspects.

When I'am designing it with Blend, the designer always put fixed size....

Here is my code :

```
<UserControl x:Class=""
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="203" Margin="53,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="/FakeData/Images/lavieestbelle.jpg" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="144" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform Rotation="-15"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="203" Margin="88,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="/FakeData/Images/lavieestbelle.jpg" Width="144"/>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="203" Margin="132.951,34.5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="/FakeData/Images/lavieestbelle.jpg" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" Width="144">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform Rotation="15"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
</Grid>
```

How can I do that ? Thank for any help

Comment: Are you trying to update it in the XAML or in the code? I am confused on why you are saying it is a fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

`Image.Stretch` property can be helpful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.stretch.aspx.